# How to flush an address range in L1 and L2 Cache from Linux kernel space on ARM v7?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a dummy driver to share kernel buffer to user space on ARM v7.
I want to implement fsync() operation for this buffer. Which APIs should I use to flush L1 and L2 cache for a given user address range in my fsync?
There are many APIs available in asm/cacheflush.h, but I am not sure weather they will flush both L1 and L2 or only L1?

Currently I am using

```
dmac_flush_range()
outer_flush_range()
```

APIs. Are they fine for the use case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARMv7 mandates that data caches behave as if [physically-indexed and physically-tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIPT)<sup>*</sup>, which means that multiple virtual addresses mapping to the same physical address are naturally coherent with each other without requiring any cache maintenance or barriers. Therefore the kernel mapping and user mapping of your buffer are already fully in sync at all times, and there's not really anything you need to do. You certainly don't have any of the VIVT cache problems of older CPUs.

That said, using those architecture-private cache APIs directly from a driver *would* get you roundly shouted at by kernel maintainers these days - drivers should normally only need to care about cache maintenance at all when DMA is involved, but correct use of the [DMA mapping API](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) already takes care of everything in that regard.

<sub>* they don't strictly have to *be* PIPT, for instance Cortex-A8's L1 [which is actually non-aliasing VIPT](https://community.arm.com/message/18888#18888) under the hood.</sub>